# Virtual Inheritance that wont show desired output

Tags: c++

I had gotten a header file named Shape.h and I was tasked for creating 4 other header files each representing shapes: Square, Rectangle, Circle and Ellipse.

The header file Shape is inherited by four other header files and the source file should give output accordingly to header files.

I wrote the codes just fine, but the output won't give the expected result, i need help here.

I asked my instructors for help, even if they helped it was time-consuming and but that was worth it.

the real deal here is that I debugged, and looked around the code and tried different things on the code but I either gets the same unwanted result or an error message.

This is Base file:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

struct Color {
  uint8_t r, g, b;
  Color(uint8_t _r, uint8_t _g, uint8_t _b) : r(_r), g(_g), b(_b) {}
};

class Shape {
public:
  Shape(Color color) : m_color(color) {}

  virtual std::string toString() const {
    return "color=" + std::to_string(m_color.r) + ',' +
           std::to_string(m_color.g) + ',' + std::to_string(m_color.b) + '\n';
  }
  virtual float getArea() const = 0;
  virtual float getCircumference() const = 0;

  virtual ~Shape();

private:
  Color m_color;
};

// note: this method was moved here to satisfy the compiler's need for an
// out-of-line virtual function
Shape::~Shape() {}
```

This is one of the 4 inheriting header files (Square.h):

```
#include "Shape.h"
#include <string>
class Square :
    public Shape
{
public:
    Square(Color rgb, float width) :Shape(rgb), w(width) {}
    std::string toString() {
        return Shape::toString() + '\n'
            + "width=" + std::to_string(w) + '\n';
    }
    float getArea() const override{
        return w*w;
    }
    float getCircumference() const override {
        return w*4;
    }
private:
    float w;
};
```

And this is the source file for testing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "Shape.h"
#include "Square.h"

void printAttributes(Shape &shape) {
    std::cout << shape.toString();
    ;
    std::cout << "area=" << std::to_string(shape.getArea()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "circumference=" << std::to_string(shape.getCircumference())
        << '\n'
        << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    Color red{255, 0, 0 };
    Square square(red, 10.0);
    printAttributes(square);
    return 0;
}
```

f.ex. a squares output should look like this:

```
color=255,0,0
width=10.000000
area=120.000000
circumference=44.000000
```

my output shows

```
color=255,0,0
area=120.000000
circumference=44.000000
```

Comment: @NathanOliver: It calls `shape.toString()` which should. But the code doesn't match the expected output by any stretch.

Comment: As I can see there is no version of the `Shape` constructor that takes: `Square(Color rgb, float width) :Shape(rgb), w(width)`.

Comment: @MooingDuck Good eyes.

Comment: `const` is missing in `toString` in derived `Square` class.

Comment: [The given code does compile and give the output as claimed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b8d3b13aca4469d), which I found surprising

Comment: *Consistently* use the `override` keyword when overriding functions in derived classes (and then ditch the redundant `virtual`). Then the compiler will warn you when you get the function signature wrong and do *not* in fact override anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Square :
    public Shape
{
public:
    Square(Color rgb, float width) :Shape(rgb), w(width) {}
    std::string toString() const {
        return Shape::toString() + '\n'
            + "width=" + std::to_string(w) + '\n';
    }
    float getArea() const override{
        return w*w;
    }
    float getCircumference() const override {
        return w*4;
    }
private:
    float w;
};
```

Add const keyword after toString method then will be override your base toString function . **foo()** and **foo() const** is not same then your code call Shape.toString(). In the virtual function table won't override your Shape::toString method.

Answer (score -1):

Corrected my previous response. Because your base class has const in the function signature and the derived class does not, the derived class toString function is actually seen as a different function. If you add const to the derived class or remove const from super class, the function works as intended.

Comment: polymorphism also works with references, which the OP is using

Comment: One fun thing about C++ is VTables are an implementation detail. They are a simple and direct solution to the problem so they are commonly used, but a sufficiently cunning (or crazy) programmer could implement polymorphism with something else. Maybe even Lego.